# Error connecting PHP to SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using a script php that connect to sqlserver but it doesn't works.

```
//connection to the database
$dbconn = mssql_connect($Server)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $Server");
if($dbconn)echo 'Connected';
//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($DB, $dbconn)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
```

![when running script it gives this error, i m using windows authentication][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9ndN.jpg

Comment: `mssql` extension is deprecated. Use [`sqlsrv`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) instead.

Comment: Is localhost running? It looks like its not.

Comment: There's another post with the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343993/how-to-connect-php-with-sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

Check [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

```
$dbconn = mysql_connect('hostname','username','password');
```

Comment: All i need to connect php to sqlserver, i have windows7 32bit,wamp server, php v5.3.0,apache2.2.11. i ve downloaded  SQLSRV30.EXE and copy the files to ext folder of php, and also i have copied ntwdblib.dll to the php directory and to appache bin directory. in the php.ini i have added the following extensions extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll . but i still get the following msg:Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl() in C:\wamp\www\TPphp\SQLServer\tp.php on line 5. What i should do to connect php to sqlserver?

Comment: "SQLServer" stands for Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. `mysql_` functions will not connect to it. New concept you should have learned a long time ago: `mysql_` functions are **deprecated** and should not be used.

Answer (score -1):

Connect using `mysql_connect()`

```
$dbconn =mysql_connect(servername,username,password);
```

example

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","me","123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
```