# How to connect PHP with SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to connect the SQLServer 2008 with the PHP 5.4.6.

But the server returns the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect ()

I have looked in many places and they all say to go in PHP.ini and uncomment the line:

```
extension = php_mysql.dll
```

But my php.ini file doesn't have this line.

This is my current code, but I've tried several others:

```
<? php 
$ server = "192.168.2.7"; 
$ database = "fd_585b0f87"; 
$ user = "sa"; 
$ password = "5c n9r1n7 @ # @ dm"; 


$ conn = mssql_connect ($ server, $ user, $ password); 
$ conn = mssql_select_db ("$ database", $ connection); 


if ($ conn) {
echo "One connection"; 


} 
>
```

Anyone know any way to fix this error? thank you

Comment: `php_mysql.dll` is not relevant for `mssql_connect()`

Answer (score 0):

`mssql_connect` went away in PHP 5.3. Here's the link for the SQL Server driver for PHP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You have the steps should I follow after downloading?

Comment: @user11699 You should check if it is installed first, do you have any output for sql server when you run `phpinfo();`? Also see this section in the php manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php

Comment: I will try this steps from this manual. But  How can I test my mssql with phpinfo() ? Sorry I'm a newbie haha